# PowerShell MgGraph Commands trowing TypeNotFound Error

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I just installed the Microsoft.Graph Module on a fresh Windows 11 installation. Connecting with Connect-MgGraph works fine but if i use any other command after successfully authenticating I get the following error.
I have found nothing about this error, but here are a few things I tried:

1. Reinstalling Microsoft.Graph module
2. Installing .NET Core 7
3. Installing Az Module

```
The type [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet] was not found.
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.Graph.Users\2.6.0\exports\ProxyCmdletDefinitions.ps1:16320
Zeichen:52
+ ... ommand -and [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePS ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Windo...n.AzurePSCmdlet:TypeName) [], ParentContainsErrorRe
   cordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue.

Comment: Probably revert to the version 2.5 until it's fixed

Comment: Using 2.5 works

Answer (score 0):

Same here, had to uninstall 2.6 but I was blocked by "Microsoft.Graph.Authentication".
I uninstalled all others modules first then "Microsoft.Graph.Authentication" with that command :

```
Get-InstalledModule Microsoft.Graph.* | ? {$_.Name -ne "Microsoft.Graph.Authentication"} | Uninstall-Module
```